# Puppeteer - click on span with specified text

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'am currently web scraping one page with puppeteer. I am trying to make something which can speed up my work.

My HTML Markup looks something like this

```
<div class="inner-wrapper" style="">
<div class="style-001">
    <ul role="listbox" aria-multiselectable="true" class="style-002">
    <li role="option" aria-selected="false" class="style-003">
        <span class="style-004">First Option</span>
    </li>
    <li role="option" aria-selected="false" class="style-003">
        <span class="style-004">Second Option</span>
    </li>
    <li role="option" aria-selected="false" class="style-003">
        <span class="style-004">Third Option</span>
    </li>      
    </ul>
</div>
```

I was trying to select specific 'li' based on span's text. This page is dynamic so sometimes 'Third Option' will have index [3] and sometimes other one. It have to be selected just by span's text because It won't work in other situations. I can't use class because this website uses same classes for every 'li'.

I did research on google and stackoverflow and didn't find working solution. I tried selecting by xpath, js selector and more. And even I tried something like this:

```
const [link] = await page.$x('//div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/span[contains(text(), "First Option")]'); 
await link.click();
```

or

```
let selectOption = await page.waitForXPath(`//div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[contains(text(),'First Option')]`);
await selectOption.click();
```

If someone can help me, I will huge appreciate.

@EDIT
If it is important clicking on any option this website changes aria-selected="false" to "true". Maybe it will help in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use `page.evaluate` and than use `querySelectorAll` and `filter` the `li` by text than use a `forEach` to click on the `il` with the specific text.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li')).filter(li => {
    return li.innerText == 'First Option' // filter il for specific text
  }).forEach(element => {
    if (element) element.click(); // click on il with specific text
  });
});
```

If the first one does not work you can try.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div > div > ul > li')).filter(li => {
    return li.innerText == 'First Option' // filter il for specific text
  }).forEach(element => {
    if (element) element.click(); // click on il with specific text
  });
});
```

You could also give this a try and i think this would be the best way todo it.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('div > div > ul > li')];
  const targetElement = elements.find(e => e.innerText == 'First Option');
  if (targetElement) targetElement.click();
});
```

or

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];
  const targetElement = elements.find(e => e.innerText == 'First Option');
  if (targetElement) targetElement.click();
});
```

Comment: OMG, you are the best, man. I am trying to find any solution for week and you did it withing hour. I didn't try every solution, but third works fine. I would like to have your brain :d, love you xoxo

Comment: Haha I'm happy i could help you! And yeah the third solution is want i would use also.

Comment: Did the API change? I'm not seeing a click method for element. InnerText isn't resolving either.

Comment: @chaostheory I don't think so, but other people in this [issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1805) had similar problems. I found that a combination of `await page.waitForSelector('.someSelector', 300);` and `await page.$eval('.someSelector', ((el) => el.click()));` worked for my use case.